# Pseudo-element :after not working anymore after upgrading 'openhtmltopdf' to v1.0.10

Tags: java, css, thymeleaf, openhtmltopdf

I'm working on a project, where we use thymeleaf to design .html files. These are being transformed to pdf using danfickles pure-Java library.
Because the framework doesn't support CSS3 features, one has to work a lot with tables and such.. In our case we used to "clean up" after specific elements, decorating them with

```
.icon-headline:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

This was used to make sure, `float: left` and such were cleared so they wouldn't interfere each other. This, let me call it, "small hack" doesn't work anymore. I noticed in the patchnotes a line about

> #711 (mixed) Better boxing for ::before and ::after content. Should now be able to define a border around pseudo content correctly.

Full patchnotes can be found [Openhtmltopdf github repo](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf)

I'm now looking for a way to reproduce this behavior. Maybe anyone has got any tip and I hope I made it clear what the problem is. If not I'm happy to clarify further.

Thanks in advance,
Ayume

Comment: I find it hard to share a minimal reproducible example hence I'm having differences because of an update of a library version. I can try a bit more using language instead of code I guess:
If anyone knew what had changed or how I could adapt my code or approach, it would be best case scenario but else I was hoping anyone could help me out to get a similar effect but maybe just not with :after
In the current code there is the CSS mentioned above, let's say after every table row or heading, to get rid off the float:left that was used. Now without that functionality everything is overlapping

Comment: This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Comment: All right. Yeah, I went through it and thanks for the input :) I found a solution to my problem by the way - I don't know if you went through my problem thoroughly.
I figured out that I still have the same functionality when using 
`display: block
clear: both
content: ""`
Not sure what has changed since the last patch but I guess sometimes it's hard to find out. Eventually if someone can explain that would be splendid! :)